# cmake to remove custom output results from a directory

Tags: cmake

I am going to tell cmake that add an `make eradicate` option so I can remove the output data from simulations in custom directories beside the default `make clean`.
I googled for a while and searched many questions unsuccessfully.

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── data
│   ├── fig
│   ├── npz
│   └── text
├── include
│   ├── functions.h
│   ├── kuramoto.h
│   └── random_seedo.h
├── scripts
│   ├── distance1.py
│   ├── distance.py
│   ├── functions.py
│   ├── plc.py
│   ├── plk.py
│   ├── plp.py
│   ├── plr.py
│   └── run.py
└── src
    ├── dat
    │   └── C.dat
    ├── functions.cpp
    ├── kuramoto.cpp
    └── main.cpp

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(test_cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11 -O2 -lm")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/g++)

file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
include_directories(include)

add_executable(prog ${SOURCES})

find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(prog GSL::gsl GSL::gslcblas)
```

so I need to eradicate like this that I usually do in hand written makefile:

```
eradicate:
    rm -r ../data/npz/* ../data/fig/* ../data/text/*
.PHONY: eradicate
```

I am not going to type each time the rm  command. some times I need to remove many file types and directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html) for that.

```
add_custom_target(eradicate
  COMMAND rm -r "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../data/npz/*" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../data/fig/*" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../data/text/*"
)
```

Note that `add_custom_target`'s target is always outdated, so it will be run *every* time.

Comment: You need to add keyword `ALL` to have it run every time by default, Otherwise it'll just run whenever you build the target.  e.g. `make eradicate` vs  `make`.

Comment: `rm -r` breaks for Command Prompt users. You could wrap that in a recursive cmake invocation with closer to `cmake -E`, though that drops flags. Also, this approach is a non-starter for cleaning up the `.ninja_log` generated file, when using cmake with ninja.